# C# PowerPoint Play Exception

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a method which has a thread and going to next slide with powerpoint duration. But after closing the presentation I need to check is it active or not.
But I couldn't figure out. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

```
private void Play()
{
    try
    {
        while (mainForm._slideIndex <= mainForm._slidescount)
        {
            if (mainForm._presentation.Slides._Index(1) != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep((int)mainForm._oSlideShowView.Slide.SlideShowTransition.Duration * 500);
            }

            if (mainForm._slideIndex == mainForm._slidescount)
            {
                if (mainForm._oSlideShowView != null)
                {
                    mainForm._oSlideShowView.First();
                    mainForm._slideIndex = 1;
                }
            }

            if (mainForm._slideIndex <= mainForm._slidescount)
            {
                if (mainForm._oSlideShowView != null)
                {
                    mainForm._oSlideShowView.Next();
                    mainForm._slideIndex++;
                }
            }
            if (mainForm._presentation.Slides._Index(1) != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep((int)mainForm._oSlideShowView.Slide.SlideShowTransition.Duration * 500);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

[Exception](http://i.hizliresim.com/52ldbL.png)